# How do I store only Time in datetime object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

How do I only store the time part in date time object? I am doing this:

```
            DateTime.TryParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), "HH:mm:ss",
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out outTime);
            Datetime LogTime = outTime;
```

But it still add date to it. I only want like `"13:01:03"` instead of `"2019-10-31 13:01:03.000"`.

Comment: Consider [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netstandard-2.1).

Answer (score 0):

Time without a date is usually meaningless.

However, if you must store only the time, then [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) would be appropriate.  It offers some advantage over `UInt64` by way of convenient methods of transforming milliseconds into other time units.

This will end up holding the milliseconds since "the beginning", where "the beginning" will have to be defined by you.